# LD_LIBRARY_PATH Defining required libs

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk

I want to be sure about any required libraries to be added into the developed Android App. Thus, I am trying to have it properly defined into [LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7355571/qmake-pro-file-not-parsed-correctly-to-generate-ld-library-path). The command ldd is used to check what libraries are needed for my Qt application.

When I run ldd on Ubuntu, it was supposed to give me the list of libs required for MyApp. However, this is what I get so far:

```
$ cd MyAppProjFolder
$ ldd MyApp | grep libQt
ldd: ./MyApp: not regular file
$ file MyApp
MyApp: directory
$ cd Debug
$ ldd MyApp | grep libQt
./MyApp: No such file or directory
$ cd android-build
$ ldd MyApp | grep libQt
./MyApp: No such file or directory
$ cd bin
$ ldd MyApp | grep libQt
./MyApp: No such file or directory
```

To find where the executable is located I run the commands:

```
$ find /home/user/MyAppProjFolder -name MyApp
/MyAppProjFolder/.../bin/classes/org/qtproject/example/MyApp
$ ldd MyApp | grep libQt
./MyApp: No such file or directory
```

What am I missing here? The executable file generated is different from the name of the defined project/app?

Comment: what does `file ./MyApp` return in its folder?

Comment: @Laszlo Papp. I entered the main folder and run ldd with the name of my application. from the root folder from the project it gives: ldd: ./MyApp: not regular file. Let me know if it is what you mean?

Comment: `file` is a Linux command to return information about the file type. Since you are getting "not regular file", I would like to see what kind of file this is...

Comment: thanks. just added in my post the output from "file MyApp".

Comment: 'ldd' should be run on your executable, not on your directory. You should know where your executable is located, and you should run it on that. So the main question is where your executable is located. Go figure that out. Also, you will need to use the "Android" ldd rather than your hosts.

Comment: check my update. any hints?

Comment: I removed the qtcreator tag because it seems to be not related to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the conversation in the comments, you seem to have the following mistakes:

1) You are trying to run `ldd` on a directory or non-existent files.

2) You seem to be running `ldd` from your host on the target binary. It is not necessarily the same.

My advice is to locate your executable and make sure you run the proper `ldd` on that.

Edit: since you modified the point of your question to a certain extent after the initial post, here goes the reply:

> What am I missing here?

How to use find and ldd on the same file.

> The executable file generated is different from the name of the defined project/app?

It is something that /you/ define in your buildsystem, so we cannot know, especially if you do not paste the relevant code.

Comment: you mean.. the executable is generated and placed nowhere in the host, but in the target device?

Comment: @Hatsune: really, you need to find your executable. It is really basics...

Comment: It looks quite a bit of handholding you need, but you should have used `file /MyAppProjFolder/.../bin/classes/org/qtproject/example/MyApp`, and if that is not the executable, then you do not have an executable built provided you know the name of your executable...

Comment: @HatsuneOko: have you found your executable on your host machine?

Comment: thanks for asking. I really appreciate your supporting hand. I looked in the folder MyApp. here are files there: BuildConfig.class  R$attr.class  R$layout.class
R$array.class      R.class       R$string.class
... I also run the command you mentioned and the output was: ldd: ./MyApp: not regular file. The same for running the command: file ./MyApp. Despite that, the program build and run into the android device.... The error I was worried about, I found that is indeed a bug, and in fact a warning that doesn't block the app from running. So, thanks very much again. and happy holidays!