# Qt C++: Include all library files in project folder

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, qt-creator

Using Qt Creator, I created my own personal **shared library** which I am currently using in a project that I am working on. What I want to do is to put the **.so/.dll** file in a **lib/** folder of the application in which I used the following code in my .pro file:

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/lib/

win32 {
    SHARED_LIB_FILES = $$files($$PWD/lib/*.dll)
    for(FILE, SHARED_LIB_FILES) {
        BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
        LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,\.dll,)
    }
}
unix {
    SHARED_LIB_FILES = $$files($$_PRO_FILE_PWD_/lib/*.so)
    for(FILE, SHARED_LIB_FILES) {
        BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
        LIBS += -l$$replace(BASENAME,\.so,)
    }
}
```

But when I build the project I get the following errors for functions used from the library files:

```
Undefined reference to 'Class::function()'
```

How can I dynamically include the library file from the **lib/** folder without encountering the mentioned errors?

**UPDATE**

Compiler Output:

```
09:56:53: Running steps for project PocketList...
09:56:53: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
09:56:53: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -m64 -Wl,-O1 -o PocketList main.o combotonselect.o ComListaCodigos.o ComEditor.o ComRecordatorio.o ComControlador.o Aplicacion.o ComNota.o ComElidedLabel.o ComDashPad.o AppRecordatorios.o AppCodigos.o ComVinchero.o AppVincheros.o Mod.o AppDashboard.o ComLogger.o ComLlave.o ComListaNotas.o AppNotas.o VentanaPrincipal.o AppConvertidorMetrico.o qrc_res.o moc_combotonselect.o moc_ComListaCodigos.o moc_ComEditor.o moc_ComRecordatorio.o moc_ComControlador.o moc_Aplicacion.o moc_ComNota.o moc_ComElidedLabel.o moc_ComResizeImageDialog.o moc_ComDashPad.o moc_AppRecordatorios.o moc_Control.o moc_AppCodigos.o moc_ComVinchero.o moc_AppVincheros.o moc_Mod.o moc_ObservadorVincheros.o moc_AppDashboard.o moc_ObservadorCuota.o moc_ObservadorConexion.o moc_ComLogger.o moc_ComLlave.o moc_ComListaNotas.o moc_AppNotas.o moc_VentanaPrincipal.o moc_AppConvertidorMetrico.o moc_WorkerObservadorVincheros.o moc_WorkerObservadorCuota.o moc_WorkerObservadorConexion.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/media/omari/EXT/Programación/Qt\ Creator/PocketList/lib/ -lQt5Multimedia -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Network -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
main.o: En la función `ConvertidorMetrico::cargar()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv[_ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv]+0x9b0): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
main.cpp:(.text._ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv[_ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv]+0xa49): referencia a `Controlador::split(QString, QString)' sin definir
main.cpp:(.text._ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv[_ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv]+0xda1): referencia a `Controlador::split(QString, QString)' sin definir
main.cpp:(.text._ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv[_ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv]+0xf0b): referencia a `Controlador::split(QString, QString)' sin definir
Makefile:292: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'PocketList'
main.cpp:(.text._ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv[_ZN18ConvertidorMetrico6cargarEv]+0x1100): referencia a `Controlador::split(QString, QString)' sin definir
AppRecordatorios.o: En la función `AppRecordatorios::guardar()':
AppRecordatorios.cpp:(.text+0x21b3): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppRecordatorios.o: En la función `AppRecordatorios::cargarDatos()':
AppRecordatorios.cpp:(.text+0x2ea1): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppRecordatorios.cpp:(.text+0x3297): referencia a `Controlador::split(QString, QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.o: En la función `AppCodigos::actualizarCodigos()':
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0xecf): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x124b): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppCodigos.o: En la función `AppCodigos::cargarDatos()':
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x16be): referencia a `Controlador::esDirExistente(QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x1919): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x1c6a): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x1e42): referencia a `Controlador::crearDirectorio(QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.o: En la función `AppCodigos::eliminarCodigo()':
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x2ef7): referencia a `Controlador::eliminarArchivo(QString)' sin definir
AppCodigos.o: En la función `AppCodigos::addCodigo()':
AppCodigos.cpp:(.text+0x3214): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppVincheros.o: En la función `AppVincheros::guardar()':
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x1709): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppVincheros.o: En la función `AppVincheros::getCantidadVinchero(QString, QString)':
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x1e02): referencia a `Controlador::getVinculosURL(QString)' sin definir
AppVincheros.o: En la función `AppVincheros::addVinchero()':
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x3e4c): referencia a `Controlador::esUrlValido(QString)' sin definir
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x3f14): referencia a `Controlador::leerURL(QString)' sin definir
AppVincheros.o: En la función `AppVincheros::actualizarVinchero()':
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x4744): referencia a `Controlador::esUrlValido(QString)' sin definir
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x479b): referencia a `Controlador::leerURL(QString)' sin definir
AppVincheros.o: En la función `AppVincheros::cargarDatos()':
AppVincheros.cpp:(.text+0x4ee0): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::configurarObservadorConexion()':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x328f): referencia a `Controlador::existeFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x3315): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::actualizarCuotaObservada()':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x432f): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x4f1e): referencia a `Controlador::eliminarArchivo(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::solicitarCuota(bool)':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x5a9a): referencia a `Controlador::hayConexion()' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::configurarObservadorCuota()':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x6747): referencia a `Controlador::existeFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x67cc): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::actualizarCuotaObservada(Control::Cuota*)':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x7d6a): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `AppDashboard::setProxyConexion()':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x8c03): referencia a `Controlador::eliminarArchivo(QString)' sin definir
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text+0x921b): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppDashboard.o: En la función `Control::getCuota(QString)':
AppDashboard.cpp:(.text._ZN7Control8getCuotaE7QString[_ZN7Control8getCuotaE7QString]+0xc2): referencia a `Controlador::leerURL(QString)' sin definir
ComLlave.o: En la función `ComLlave::autenticar()':
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x10e8): referencia a `Controlador::cifrarContrasenna(QString)' sin definir
ComLlave.o: En la función `ComLlave::cargarDatos()':
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x154b): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
ComLlave.o: En la función `ComLlave::cambiarContrasenna()':
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x3392): referencia a `Controlador::cifrarContrasenna(QString)' sin definir
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x371a): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x3a3c): referencia a `Controlador::cifrarContrasenna(QString)' sin definir
ComLlave.cpp:(.text+0x3ca0): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.o: En la función `AppNotas::guardar()':
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x11f2): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x1b73): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
AppNotas.o: En la función `AppNotas::cargarDatos()':
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x217f): referencia a `Controlador::esDirExistente(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x21dc): referencia a `Controlador::crearDirectorio(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x25bd): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x2cb9): referencia a `Controlador::leerFichero(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.o: En la función `AppNotas::eliminarCuaderno()':
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x48b9): referencia a `Controlador::eliminarArchivo(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.o: En la función `AppNotas::eliminarNota()':
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x4b34): referencia a `Controlador::eliminarArchivo(QString)' sin definir
AppNotas.o: En la función `AppNotas::addNota()':
AppNotas.cpp:(.text+0x53e7): referencia a `Controlador::escribirFichero(QString, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)' sin definir
VentanaPrincipal.o: En la función `VentanaPrincipal::VentanaPrincipal(QWidget*)':
VentanaPrincipal.cpp:(.text+0x1015): referencia a `Controlador::esDirExistente(QString)' sin definir
VentanaPrincipal.cpp:(.text+0x15c7): referencia a `Controlador::crearDirectorio(QString)' sin definir
AppConvertidorMetrico.o: En la función `AppConvertidorMetrico::convertir(QString)':
AppConvertidorMetrico.cpp:(.text+0x3492): referencia a `te_interp' sin definir
AppConvertidorMetrico.cpp:(.text+0x3826): referencia a `te_interp' sin definir
moc_ObservadorVincheros.o: En la función `ObservadorVincheros::run()':
moc_ObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv[_ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv]+0x28): referencia a `Controlador::hayConexion()' sin definir
moc_ObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv[_ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv]+0x2fe): referencia a `Controlador::leerURL(QString)' sin definir
moc_ObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv[_ZN19ObservadorVincheros3runEv]+0x5f7): referencia a `Controlador::getVinculosURL(QString)' sin definir
moc_WorkerObservadorVincheros.o: En la función `WorkerObservadorVincheros::process()':
moc_WorkerObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv[_ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv]+0x28): referencia a `Controlador::hayConexion()' sin definir
moc_WorkerObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv[_ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv]+0x2fe): referencia a `Controlador::leerURL(QString)' sin definir
moc_WorkerObservadorVincheros.cpp:(.text._ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv[_ZN25WorkerObservadorVincheros7processEv]+0x5f7): referencia a `Controlador::getVinculosURL(QString)' sin definir
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [PocketList] Error 1
09:56:54: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project PocketList (kit: Linux)
The kit Linux has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
09:56:54: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Comment: On Win32 you need to include **.lib** and not **.dll** Informtion for linker is stored in .lib files on windows. dll's are used at runtime

Comment: But I get the same error on Linux.

Comment: On linux the same probably applies, except the `.lib` is a `.a`.

Comment: Have you tried adding the path to the libraries to the loader's LD_LIBRARAY_PATH on Linux?

Comment: @nwp No, on Linux you just have dynamic libraries (`.so`) and static libraries (`.a`). On Windows you have dynamic libraries (`.dll`), import libraries (`.lib` or `.a`) and static libraries (`.lib` or `.a`). MinGW toolchains generates `.a` instead of `.lib`, but the usage is the same. The point is on Linux you link directly to the dynamic library.

Comment: @AA how do I do that?

Comment: @OmariCelestine What is the command line that is used to invoke the linker ?

Comment: @BenjaminT I'm not sure to what you are referring. Could you explain to what exactly you are referring as my knowledge is not well versed in this area.

Comment: There are different ways to configure it but for the test you could `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./lib;` , if your libs are in lib subdir, before you start your app

Comment: @AA Would that be using the .pro file?

Comment: @OmariCelestine To build your project you run `qmake` and then `make`. This will execute commands that invoke the compiler and the linker in order to compile you source files into a binary. The error about "undefined reference" is a linker error, so to help you it would be nice to know the exact command that was used to run the linker.

Comment: @BenjaminT then thing is all that is done by Qt Creator.

Comment: I don't know how to do it from .pro file. Currently we are using the QtCreator's  *Project >run >Add build library search path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH* for Desktop or just a var in the *Run Environment* for remote. But you can look at the `ld-linux`s manpage on how to do it on deployment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7403314/8918119

Comment: @OmariCelestine You have a "Compile Output" panel in Qt Creator where you should have all the ouputs from qmake and make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're including *lib* (from library file name) in your LIBS. Try this:

```
BASENAME = $$basename(FILE)
LIBNAME = $$replace(BASENAME, lib, )
LIBS += -l$$replace(LIBNAME,\.so,)
```

At least for unix, convention says to omit the *lib* prefix of the library file name (e.g. libname.so => -lname)

**Update, based on the compile output you posted:**

Looking at the line that starts with g++, you succeeded in providing the lib directory to the linker

```
-L/media/omari/EXT/Programación/Qt\ Creator/PocketList/lib/
```

but failed to pass the libraries, since the only ones I see are those:

```
-lQt5Multimedia 
-lQt5Widgets 
-lQt5Gui 
-lQt5Network 
-lQt5Core 
-lGL 
-lpthread
```

Check that the directory is the one, and it contains the needed files.
Also, use `message()` function in your pro file, to debug it.
For example:

```
message( LIBNAME )
```

Comment: In the unix section, you're passing the wrong names to LIBS. I will edit the answer to explain this better.

Comment: Please, post your compile output from qtcreator.

Comment: Isn't it just the **.so** file that I have to include in the **lib/** folder?

Comment: You must provide the linker the definition of that Controlador class. Is it in a shared library? If yes: is that library in your lib folder? If yes, why your pro file fails to add it to the LIBS and it doesn't show up in your g++ line? Did you use the message() function to check, as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, it is a shared library and the **.so** file is in the lib folder and I have added the message() function but now I am unable to update the compiler output code in my question as it now surpasses the question word limit. Is there something specific I should look for or a specific part of the output that I should include?